# Why would someone not return after asking for more details on a question?

Tags: discussion

I have been asking some questions lately, and one thing that broke my heart was there were some people who commented on my question asking things like: "do you want A solution or B solution?" or, "can you give my the function for this and that?".

This made me think that these people were going to give me the solution, after I responded. Alas, they never came back. I tried to mention their name in the comments, but there's no sign of their return days afterwards :(.

Why would this occur?

Comment: ... broke your heart? Come on, dramatic much?

Comment: Everyone here is just volunteering their own time, they have lives too. They don't *have* to answer your questions. If they are having to ask for clarification, maybe your question wasn't very clear, or perhaps you took too long to respond to the comments.

Comment: How did you "mention their name"? Did you use the `@` notation, as described in the [comment editing help](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)? As for why they did not return - consider that there are more people that feel qualified to comment on an unclear question than those that feel qualified to answer a clarified one. Or the possibility that any edits were not enough to actually clarify the issue.

Comment: You also have to consider that the individual might not have known the answer, but knew something was missing.  I do that occassionally.  If I'm looking at a new question and see something that is unclear or missing, I will comment to try to get the OP while he is still there to help potentially answers who show up later.

Comment: Thanks guys for your comments, they are all helpful

Comment: Or maybe they just lost interest in the topic or no longer had the time to answer after clarification.

Comment: Suppose I see an unclear question. I comment asking something that will clarify whether it is a question I can answer. The edited question is clearly something different that I can't answer. What should I do? Posting "Sorry, can't answer that." would clutter the site.

Comment: learn to post concise questions with only the releveant code included. When you dump too much code in a question that's a great way to get ignored

Comment: It's entirely feasible that by the time you'd provided more information, they were no longer available to help. For example, I've just asked for more information on a question, but I'm about to go to bed. I'm hoping that the OP will edit the question with more information which will help someone *else* help that person.

Comment: Your problem is far less common that the opposite: Someone asks a "question", only omits virtually all useful info.  Many people come and add comments asking for info.  The OP never appears again.

Answer (score 3):

On Stack Overflow there is a review system. The community have a list of questions and answers for new people like you. The purpose is to review each posts and decide, is it a good one or a bad one. This is how this site work.

If it is a bad one, you have 3 possibilities:

- Downvote
- Flag (off-topic, problems)
- Comment (that you should improve your post)

If it is a good one:

- Upvote
- Comment (interesting things that would help to make the post even better)

You can do all of the above, or only one. If somebody comments that you should provide more code, or explain the specific problem, it does not mean that they can help you on your specific question. If *does* mean that they're trying to help you improve your question/answer. If you improve it, you have a better chance of getting an answer, but there is no guarantee.

Always keep in mind that there are 783,713 unanswered questions. Some people invest much of their free time in helping the thousands of people who ask. That's why we need this voting system. Stack Overflow is not a support forum, for people which haven't learnt the basics. It is a Q&A Site for interesting things for which there is no current solution to. It is not the right site for syntax errors and simple logical problems.

Comment: Hi. I've edited your answer and I hope you take it the right way. Your English is pretty good; the main difference is that nouns are normally lower-case. Danke, dass Sie nach Meta kommen.